# mongodump to another host

Tags: bash, mongodb, mongodump

I have the following script:

```
mongodump --gzip  -d  foobar \
--excludeCollection=foo1 \
--excludeCollection=foo2  \
--excludeCollection=foo3 \
--excludeCollection=foo4 -o ./
```

But the dump is too large for the server it's on, it's literally taking up all the disk space. Is there anyway to make it dump to another host? Maybe using scp?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to use mongodump from anther computer, if the database is accessible, using the --host parameter and any credentials you may need. It's quite similar to using the mongo shell to connect to a remote instance.

Comment: To use this feature you must have auth enabled and have user/pass on the target database correct?